# Mutate Variables with String Names (Python)

Tags: python

If I have Bag(a=1,b=2,c=3) and I want to change the individual values. I can call self.a = 10 so my updated output would be: Bag(a=10,b=2,c=3).

If k = a and I have the code:

```
temp = ("self." + str(k))
print(temp) --> self.a
```

How can I do something like:

```
temp = 10
```

So it updates the bag (not temp itself to 10)?

Thanks

Comment: There is no `Bag` class in the Python standard library. How is `Bag` defined in your code? Do you mean a `dict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `setattr`:

```
setattr(self, k, 10)
```